# Android ViewPager as a Gallery

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery

I've read that the Gallery component is deprecated, so I've used the ViewPager instead, to get a horizontal scrolling list of fairly complex views for a large dataset. This is working fine, but I really want to be able to see part of the next and previous views, as I do with the Gallery. If I set a negative page margin, this shows part of the next view correctly (on the right hand side), but not the previous one. I've tried various adjustments to width and layout_margin, with no success.

Are there any other options I can try? Is the ViewPager really just for single pages at a time? Should I resort to the Gallery component? It seems like a fairly straightforward requirement.

Comment: I've tried to explain here how I have done it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18983211/555914