# Create Windows Phone Styled screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android XML layout and trying to make a layout that is similar to windows phone home screen. Following image tells what i am looking for.

[image: swiping should change the view]

What I have tried,

1) Horizontal Scroll View: this works for left-right swipe until the grid or list does not have a vertical scroll bar

2) Linear Layout with orientation Horizontal: Same issue as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gesture detector to detect a swipe left or right.

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

You can then add an animation to animate the movement from one view to the other. How this works varies depending on how your layout is structured ( i.e. two views in one layout with one hidden, fragments that get swapped out ). There are a lot of examples on stack overflow.

[swap fragment in an activity via animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876126/swap-fragment-in-an-activity-via-animation)

There is a Gallery View, but this is deprecated in API 16. They  suggest ViewPager or HorizontalScrollView neither of which really provides the same functionality.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Here are some other options that I personally have not used.

[Options for replacing the deprecated Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833889/options-for-replacing-the-deprecated-gallery)

Comment: so basically i keep two views in a relative layout (or do i need any other layout) and fill them to parent, one being invisible. and on each view's swipe i toggle there state...

Comment: You can keep two views in a single relative layout or you can use two fragments and swap them when you detect the gesture. The animations are a little different depending on your approach. Other than the example included try searching "slide animation hidden view android" on google. You will find a ton of examples.

Comment: this solutin allows the swipe but causes another issue where list and grid box do not scroll. I think this is because of the  onScroll being overridden by SimpleOnGestureListener. I tried to return true from onScroll but the list and grid do not scroll

Comment: I assume you hook the GestureDector up in onTouchEvent and you are still passing the events by calling super.onTouchEvent()

Comment: I did that.. but was not working. I have switched to viewpager controll

Answer (score 0):

I got this working using the ViewPager controller available in android

working code can be found here
https://github.com/harshitgoel96/ZoZo-Launcher-2

its still a work in progress, but my main two page start is working as expected.